# How do I initialize LSTM weights from Numpy arrays correctly in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the same question for `tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell` and `tf.contrib.cudnn_rnn.CudnnCompatibleLSTMCell`:

How do I initialize the LSTM weights from numpy arrays correctly? The following code-snipped executes, but does not seem
to do what I am looking for:

```
train_data = np.load('mnist_train_data.npy').reshape(-1,28,28)
train_label = np.load('mnist_train_label.npy')

params = [np.random.randn(28+128, 4*128), np.zeros(4*128)]

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[54999, 28, 28])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, None)
state = LSTMStateTuple(*(tf.zeros((54999, 128), dtype=tf.float32) for _ in range(2)))

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell(128)
cell.build(tf.TensorShape((None, 28)))
cell.set_weights(params)

initial_weights = cell.get_weights()

print(np.array_equal(params[0], initial_weights[0]))

w1 = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(128, 10), dtype=tf.float32)
b1 = tf.Variable(np.zeros(10), dtype=tf.float32)

full_seq, current_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X, initial_state=state, dtype=tf.float32)
output = tf.matmul(current_state[1], w1)
output += b1
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(y, output)

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(1):
        feed_dict = {X: train_data, y: train_label}
        sess.run(train_step, feed_dict=feed_dict)

final_weights = cell.get_weights()

print(np.array_equal(initial_weights[0], final_weights[0]))
```

This prints out  `False` in the first print-statement, so the numpy arrays do not actually seem to be used as weights.

Moreover, after the training session, this prints out `True` thus implying, that these weights are not actually updated during training.

Thanks in advance for any help on the subject.

Comment: can you show your full model and training code

Comment: The original model/training code is embedded in another framework, but here is an mnist-example that is functionally equivalent. The first print statement yields ```False```, the second one yields ```True```.